# How to match zero or more with XPath?

Tags: python, regex, xml, xpath, lxml

I am using `lxml` with python as follows:

```
trs = doc.xpath("//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table/tr")
if not trs:
    trs = doc.xpath("//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")
```

So the problem is the `tbody`.  I want to know if I can change the two XPath expressions into one with something like `?` in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the or operator: `|` as follows

```
"//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table/tr
|
//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr"
```

Answer (score 1):

To select `tr` elements under `//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table` regardless of whether there's an intervening `tbody`, use `//` again in your XPath:

```
"//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table//tr"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "deep" your structure is, but if there is only one dimension of `tr` elements directly below your `table` / `tbody` element then you could shorten it to:

```
//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table[./tr | ./tbody]//tr
```

Otherwise (if there is a deep structure with more `tr` elements in deeper levels, that you're not interested in, than I also do not know any other solution than the one @hjpotter92 already gave.